# React-Bootstrap nav stacked not showing a vertical navbar

Tags: nav, react-bootstrap

Tried to create a vertical navbar as suggested in th docs in

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/

```
const navInstance = (
    <Nav bsStyle="pills" stacked activeKey={1} onSelect={handleSelect}>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/home">
            NavItem 1 content
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Item">
            NavItem 2 content
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={3} disabled>
            NavItem 3 content
        </NavItem>
    </Nav>
);
```

But it seems that the stacked keyword does nothing and the nav appears horizontal:
[The result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFh3I.jpg)

And this is what it should look like:
[Snapshot of docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxnUl.jpg)
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add bootstrap css explicitly.
[Bootstrap Guide for react](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/)

Add following links to your public/index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```